Enforcing Field security in Apex - Schema.objectType.sobject_name.fields.field_name VS sobject_name.field_name.getDescribe() VS stripInaccessible()
Currently, there are at least four ways I am aware of to check/enforce Field Access while running Apex:

Calling sobject_name.field_name.getDescribe().isUpdateable();

Example: Account.Description.getDescribe().isUpdateable();


Calling Schema.sObjectType.sobject_name.fields.field_name.isUpdateable();

Example: Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Description.isUpdateable();
This is currently a method mentioned in documentation on Enforcing Object and Field Permissions


Calling Security.stripInaccessible() with proper AccessType Enum

Example:
Account acc = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.UPDATABLE, accounts).getRecords()[0];


Using Query on FieldPermissions:

Example: SELECT PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions WHERE Field = 'Account.Description'
I believe it is only option (for now) to check the exact Permission Set as well



Are there any meaningful differences between these, especially first two, in terms of security or performance?
Let's take as an example such code, using the first mentioned method:
public class with sharing AccountHandler {

    public static Account createAccountFromWrapper(AccountWrapper wrapper) {

        Account accountToCreate = new Account();

        if (Account.Name.getDescribe().isCreatable()) {
            accountToCreate.Name = wrapper.Name;
        }
        if (Account.Description.getDescribe().isCreatable()) {
            accountToCreate.Description = wrapper.Description;
        }
        if (Account.CustomField__c.getDescribe().isCreatable()) {
            accountToCreate.CustomField__c = wrapper.CustomField;
        }

        insert accountToCreate as user;
        return accountToCreate;
    }

}

What I immidiately see is using a Security.stripInaccessible() can make the whole block shorter, as we can remove all ifs, add one or two lines with Security.stripInaccessible() to the very end to remove fields that the User do not have access to and we are ready to go.
The only benefit of using checks with .isCreatable() that I see is when we need to run additional code to fill that value, for example getting User with SOQL for OwnerId assignment - with using the if-checks, we can save these SOQL limits and CPU time. In that use case, the first option with calling Account.Description. and second with Schema.sObjectType. looks identical to me.
SOQL query with FieldPermissions looks like very specific stuff if we must be super aware of Permission Sets used, although I do not see immidiate use case for that besides creating custom component to manage permissions easier in managed package or so.

Regarding the first 2 methods of checking field access in Apex:

Calling sobject_name.field_name.getDescribe().isUpdateable();
Calling Schema.sObjectType.sobject_name.fields.field_name.isUpdateable();

In my opinion, there is no security difference between these 2 methods, because both achieve the same thing but there seems to be a performance difference.
Below is an analysis of performance time between all 4 methods, but  remember that Salesforce org is a shared resource and performance depend on activity on the org/instance.
The analysis below was done in a developer org so the execution time might vary in production or sandbox org.
Script to check run time in milisecond (ms):
Long timeFrom = System.now().getTime();

System.debug(Account.Description.getDescribe().isUpdateable()); 
//System.debug(Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Description.isUpdateable());
//Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.UPDATABLE, [SELECT id, Description from account limit 1]); 
//FieldPermissions fieldperm = [SELECT PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions WHERE Field = 'Account.Description' limit 1]; 

Long timeTo = System.now().getTime();
Long runTimeDiff = timeTo - timeFrom ;
System.debug('Runtime -- ' + runTimeDiff + '(ms)');

Script to check CPU time in milisecond (ms):
Integer cpuTimeFrom = Limits.getCpuTime();

System.debug(Account.Description.getDescribe().isUpdateable()); 
//System.debug(Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Description.isUpdateable()); 
//Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.UPDATABLE, [SELECT id, Description from account limit 1]); 
//FieldPermissions fieldperm = [SELECT PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions WHERE Field = 'Account.Description' limit 1]; 

Integer cpuTimeDiff = Limits.getCpuTime() - cpuTimeFrom;
System.debug('CPU time -- ' +cpuTimeDiff + '(ms)' );

Analysis result:
Each script was executed 5 times to have a comparison sample of run time v/s CPU time.
System.debug(Account.Description.getDescribe().isUpdateable()); //Runtime: 0-5ms v/s CPU time:0-1ms
System.debug(Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Description.isUpdateable()); //Runtime: 1-7ms v/s CPU time: 1-2ms
Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.UPDATABLE, [SELECT id, Description from account limit 1]); //Runtime: 12-20ms v/s CPU time: 6-9ms
FieldPermissions fieldperm = [SELECT PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions WHERE Field = 'Account.Description' limit 1]; //Runtime: 135-309ms v/s CPU time:105-137ms

Based on above results :

schema option takes longer to execute though the difference is not big but once again it will depend on org activity.
Accessing the sobject directly Account.Description.... seems more practical/quickest path instead of going through the schema path Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Description... (this is based on my experience in Apex, could not find relevant documents to support this reasoning)
The method Security.stripInaccessible depends on your use case and it has its advantages especially if you need to check/enforce FLS on multiple fields.
As expected, the SOQL on FieldPermissions takes longer to execute than the previous methods since it executes a query and the Field column is not indexed.


@dphil does this provide the answers you were looking for
